# VLC | video as wallpaper | wallpaper stays in foreground hiding the taskbar and desktop icons

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, desktop-customization

I am using VLC to set a video as my desktop wallpaper on Windows 10.

What is happening:

VLC runs the video as desktop wallpaper, but the video stays in the foreground and is always hiding my taskbar and desktop icons. When I press the Windows Key from keyboard, it shows the taskbar temporarily as long as the video is out of focus (desktop icons are still hidden).

What I want to happen:

I want the video in the background (as wallpaper) with my desktop icons and taskbar always visible. I mean the video should run in the background (not in the foreground) like a normal wallpaper (it stays in the background).

The script I am using in a batch file is:

```
@echo off
title MyTitle

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --no-embedded-video --no-qt-fs-controller --qt-start-minimized --qt-system-tray --video-wallpaper --playlist-autostart --playlist-tree "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VLC\Videos"
```

Comment: Having this same problem and it's really frustrating.  After some research it may be a bug in 3.x?  Also most tutorials reference "Set as directx wallpaper" but I don't have that option.

Comment: That's the way VLC works, so you should look for another product. Suggestions: (1) Possibly [KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/), (2) [DeskScapes](https://www.stardock.com/products/deskscapes/) (€5.99), (3) [PUSH Video Wallpaper](https://www.push-entertainment.com/video-wallpaper/) ($8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio, @Kyle and @harrymc,
Thank you so much all of you for your response.

I found a third party app that does NOT consume much of your resources and does the job.

The app name is MLW (my live wallpaper).
Link:
https://mylivewallpapers.com/how-to-set-live-wallpaper-for-your-desktop-using-mlwapp/

There is a variety of amazing live wallpapers in this link:
https://mylivewallpapers.com/

I am not sure if the app is malware or not  but it has been a week using it and it hasn't harmed my computer yet.

Answer (score 3):

Well at one time VLC's desktop mode seems to have been able to show both the taskbar and desktop icons (see [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18167/set-a-video-as-your-desktop-wallpaper-with-vlc/)) but it seems that feature isn't working correctly anymore and hasn't for years. I tried looking around the VLC forum for solutions and the only output that currently seems to work is Direct3D9 video output (I tested all the other outputs in the latest VLC version to make sure), as Sancho pointed. I did see one solution on the VLC forums that I didn't think of and though it doesn't perfectly solve the problem it may be a useful substitute if you don't wish to use a third party program. If you right click the taskbar and look at toolbars (at the top), you'll see an option that says desktop which will place an icon that when clicked allows you to select your desktop icons from a list.

update: After thinking about it a little more a better solution would probably be to use a earlier version as a portable app simply for the wallpaper. The Think Geek article I linked was published in 2017 so I checked the portable versions published in 2017 and it seems that it was likely 2.2.5-2.2.8. Download it and follow the instructions listed in the article but simply make sure it doesn't override your file associations for your installed/current version of VLC. [Portable Apps - VLC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/VLC%20Media%20Player%20Portable/)

Comment: Your edit is the best answer. Awarded bounty.

Comment: Tested this and it works but note that it overlays the video over the existing wallpaper. Setting your wallpaper to a solid black fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My system is Win 10 + VLC 3.0.7.1 from PortableApps.

This hopefully approaches a solution for you.
With the following command line

```
"Path-to-VLC\VLCPortable.exe" --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --no-embedded-video --no-qt-fs-controller --qt-start-minimized --aspect-ratio 16:9 --no-skins2-systray --no-qt-system-tray --hotkeys-mousewheel-mode=2 --no-disable-screensaver --loop --noaudio --video-wallpaper "Path-to-video\video.mpg"
```

and setting in VLC `Tools` -> `Prefrences` -> `Video` -> `Output` -> `Direct3D9 video output`
I get a video playing as wallpaper, behind the task bar (either auto-hiding or not).
The desktop icons still are behind the playing video.
`DirectX (DirectDraw) video output` did not work.

I wouldn't be sure if choosing some other option, in your system, works well.
I'd suggest you try.

Answer (score 1):

VLC will obscure the desktop icons, and that's the way it works.
You need a third-party product for it to work in the way you require.

- [Desktop Live Wallpapers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/desktop-live-wallpapers/9nz370xbfqmg#activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
  Freemium software, free for some video types.
- [KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/)
  Free and open-source, and is said to do animated wallpaper, but I did not find it in
  the online documentation.
- [Stardock DeskScapes](https://www.stardock.com/products/deskscapes/)
  €5.99 with trial.
- [PUSH Video Wallpaper](https://www.push-entertainment.com/video-wallpaper/)
  $8 with trial.

Comment: Well now I really wish I'd bought the Humble Stardock Bundle.

Comment: Went ahead and purchased Object Desktop with DeskScapes and I do not see any way to do live H.264 streams.

Comment: I don't use DeskScapes, but this feature the first one in the [list](https://www.stardock.com/products/deskscapes/)! Look into the help that presumably came with the product. If still in doubt, you could ask their Support.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: Please take care when commenting to address the right person. Addressing the poster is done below the post itself, and in the case of this comment also possible below Kyle's answer. I'm really not concerned here.